# Is there any alternative to Anti-Social application for Windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec, productivity

[Anti-Social](http://anti-social.cc/) is a simple but useful application that disables access to popular Social services (e.g. Facebook, Twitter) and hence increase your productivity. It's a subset of [Freedom](http://macfreedom.com/).

While Freedom got Windows version, Anti-Social doesn't.

Anyone knows of an alternative for Anti-Social on Windows ?

Comment: self-control? ...

Comment: @Andrew Heath: AFAIK, Self-Control is only for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Cold Turkey](http://getcoldturkey.com/).

> Cold Turkey is a free productivity program that you can use to
>   temporarily block yourself off of popular social media sites,
>   addicting websites and games.

Alternatively, you can use [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/) addon if you are using Firefox.

> LeechBlock is a simple productivity tool designed to block those
>   time-wasting sites that can suck the life out of your working day. All
>   you need to do is specify which sites to block and when to block them.

Comment: I just tried Cold Turkey, it works great. Tks man : )

Comment: If it really worked, you couldn't come here to say thank you ;)

Comment: @MSalters: it meant to block access to social services only, not superuser.com man : )

Comment: Current Cold Turkey 0.8 doesn't work on Windows 8, despite what the home page says - it runs but doesn't actually block anything. Anyone know how to fix? OR an alternative

Comment: Just a warning, the Cold Turkey service CTService.exe had over 1GB of RAM allocated and periodically using high CPU and causing my laptop CPU fan to spin up, even when inactive (the blocker hasn't been enabled this week). So uninstalled. Maybe that's related to other incompatibilities with Win8.1